# Android: Limiting EditText to numbers

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

When creating an EditText in the java portion of the application, how do you limit it to numbers like you would in the xml?  For example:

```
new EditText(this);
```

set like

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/h1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Something like this perhaps ?

```
EditText text = new EditText(this);
text.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
```

Comment: you can also do `EditText et = View.inflate(this, R.layout.et_input_number, null);`

Answer (score 12):

Use of `android:numeric` is deprecated, use `android:inputType="number"`

Answer (score 2):

Go to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) and look at the table with XML attributes. It shows you the code equivalent of each item.

In this case, it's `setRawInputType`.

Comment: setInputType might be the better choice in this case, given that it will update the KeyListener

Answer (score 2):

this will usually do it:

`android:numeric="integer"`

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the below lines in the **xml** file

To accept only Numbers put:

```
 android:inputType="number"
```

To limit the length of the input numbers:

```
android:maxLength="10"
```

To accept only specific numbers:

**EX:1** The below line accept only 1 or 0.

```
android:digits="10"
```

**EX:2** The below line accept only 2 or 3.

```
android:digits="23"
```