# How do I restrict my EditText input to numerical (possibly decimal and signed) input?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have read [Android: Limiting EditText to numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200689/android-limiting-edittext-to-numbers) and [How do I show the number keyboard on an EditText in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119583/how-do-i-show-the-number-keyboard-on-an-edittext-in-android). Unfortunately, none of them seems to fit my needs.

I want to restrict my EditText input to only numbers. However, I also want to allow signed and/or decimal input.

Here is my current code (I need to do this programmatically):

```
EditText edit = new EditText(this);

edit.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
edit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

With this, my EditText merrily restricts all input to numerical digits. Unfortunately, it doesn't allow anything else, like the decimal point.

If I change that line to `edit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL)`, the EditText accepts all input (which isn't what I want...).

I've tried combining flags (in desperation to see if it would work):

```
edit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
edit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL)
edit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED)
```

That didn't work either (the EditText accepted all input as usual).

So, how do I do this?

Comment: Programmatically? So you would be against an XML layout solution?

Comment: I wouldn't be against one, as long as I can create an EditText on the fly.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Try using [TextView.setRawInputType()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setRawInputType%28int%29) it corresponds to the `android:inputType` attribute.

Comment: How exactly would I invoke this? Do I just invoke the calls in a chain?

Comment: using your example code:
`edit.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);`

Comment: Hey its ok, I just picked the setter associated with the android input type. I'm happy you found it and I was close.  Yep, its just a bit mask with flags, not all of them but many are.

Comment: What was the solution? using any of these i still get keys i don't want like "*","#", and parentesis, etc...i only want numbers and -/+/. chars, how to do this?

Comment: Check the [InputType Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html) for more details.

Comment: This answer is actually incorrect. The user can still type spacebar if we use this. setInputType() is the way to go

Answer (score 183):

There's no reason to use `setRawInputType()`, just use `setInputType()`. However, you have to combine the class and flags with the OR operator:

```
edit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
```

Comment: Will give an uptick if you show the xml code as well for setting those flags.

Comment: This is not sufficient.  You can still type multiple decimals.  That is not a valid number.

Comment: Sometimes, Android makes me pull out my hair.  Why is something so simple so incredibly hard and bug-prone?

Comment: damn tried every thing... now i wonder in a single or static dynamic edittext it works with a simple one statement inputtype, with multiple dynamic et (et in an array) it does not i had to come here for the rescue.. thanks man

Comment: This is the right answer. setRawInputType actually doesn't work.

Comment: note that the signed flag is not needed if you don't want to allow negative values

Comment: I had to use `setRawInputType` because of problems with not accepting delimiter when setting accepted characters programatically and problems with selectionStart cursor which cannot be moved.

Answer (score 22):

Use this. Works fine

```
input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
input.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789"));
```

EDIT

kotlin version

```
fun EditText.onlyNumbers() {
    inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER or InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL or
        InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED
    keyListener = DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789")
}
```

Comment: It's That i want, Thank you

Comment: May I know how to allow them to type 11 numbers only? @V.Kalyuzhnyu

Comment: @LeonZaii allow only typing "1" and check that string length divisible by two

Answer (score 14):

The best way to do that programmatically is using the next method:

```
public static DigitsKeyListener getInstance (boolean sign, boolean decimal)
```

Returns a DigitsKeyListener that accepts the digits 0 through 9, plus the minus sign (only at the beginning) and/or decimal point (only one per field) if specified.

This solve the problem about the many '.' in EditText

```
editText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(true,true)); // decimals and positive/negative numbers. 

editText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(false,true)); // positive decimals numbers. 

editText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(false,false)); // positive integer numbers.

editText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(true,false)); // positive/negative integer numbers.
```

Comment: Nice! I can't even copy-and-paste bad characters in! (Yes, I know how to copy and paste on Android;)

Comment: Now all I need to do is alert the user if they enter a `0`, which is still forbidden...

Answer (score 13):

put this line in `xml`

```
 android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
```

Comment: I can still enter `42.5..5`. Then `Double.parseDouble()` kacks on it...

Answer (score 5):

Hi All I also had this problem. I use C# with Xamarin

Just a slight note that I hope someone else as well.

I have tried multiple of the methods mentioned here.

```
edittext1.SetRawInputType(Android.Text.InputTypes.ClassNumber | Android.Text.InputTypes.NumberFlagDecimal);
```

was the closest but still did not work. As Ralf mentioned, you could use

> edit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER |
>   InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL |
>   InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);

However in my C# I did not have this. instead you do it as follow:

```
edittext1.InputType = Android.Text.InputTypes.ClassNumber | Android.Text.InputTypes.NumberFlagDecimal;
```

Please note that the ORDER of these is important. If you put Decimal first, it will still allow you to type any Characters, where If Numer is first it is only numeric, but allows a decimal seperator!

Comment: Non programatically I manage this with just ```android:inputType="numberDecimal"```

Answer (score 2):

```
EditText edit = new EditText(this);

edit.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
edit.setInputType(EditorInfo.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED|EditorInfo.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

Answer (score 1):

TO set the input type of EditText as decimal use this code:

```
EditText edit = new EditText(this);
edit.SetRawInputType(Android.Text.InputTypes.NumberFlagDecimal | Android.Text.InputTypes.ClassNumber);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try having this in your xml of Edit Text:

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

Answer (score 0):

my solution:`

```
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
   char ch=s.charAt(start + count - 1);
   if (Character.isLetter(ch)) {
       s=s.subSequence(start, count-1);
       edittext.setText(s);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use **setRawInputType** and **setKeyListener**

```
editTextNumberPicker.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | 
                   InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL|InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED );
editTextNumberPicker.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(false,true));//set decimals and positive numbers.
```