# How do you set EditText to only accept numbers without decimals in Android?

Tags: java, android, regex

My `EditText` should only accept a 3 digit number, not any other decimal numbers. I used the below regular expression to do that but this is even accepting characters like "." and "-". So how do you avoid accepting decimal values?

**Java:**

```
pattern=Pattern.compile("[0-9]{0,2}");
```

**XML:**

```
android:digits="0123456789"
android:inputType="number"
```

Comment: Use **android:inputType="numberDecimal"**

Comment: then it accept decimal also. It should accept only 3 digit number not any thing else

Comment: @HamidShatu what is your answer? please read the question

Comment: I give it in the answer option for convenient to see.

Comment: You can check [this answer][1], that solves your problems.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32397808/2437881

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this:

```
android:inputType="number|none"
android:maxLength="3"
android:digits="0123456789"
```

Comment: only 3 digit number not anything

Comment: what u mean by 3digit number?

Comment: Ok i removed regular expression. now it is working..thank you

Comment: What does "none" means here?

Answer (score 1):

Set these in your xml of edittext...

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
android:maxLength="3"
```

Comment: Please read question. It should accept only digits not any other characters like "." or "-"

Comment: I have checked out your conditions. After adding these two attributes the **EditText** field will not take any "." or "-" and it will take only 3 digits, not more than that.

Answer (score 0):

Set this to your `EditText`

```
android:inputType:"number"
android:maxLength:"3"
```

Comment: should accept only 3 digit number not anything else

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should do it programmatically with the use of [TextWacher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) class

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
{
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable delayedAction = null;

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged( CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
    {}

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged( CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
    {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged( final Editable s)
    {}
});
```

Comment: i got the answer from SMR. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this in your EditText xml declaration :

```
android:inputType="number|none"
```

Enjoy coding :)

Comment: This answer was already provided by Mr Hamid Shatu as the first comment...So try to be more dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32397808/2437881) to solve your problem. Also to limited the number of digits you can use:

```
android:maxLength="3"
```

as other users answer you above.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Event if the input is not accept decimal. In my case if i set text to input programmatically, the result will be decimal (added .0 at the end). So, to solve that i replace it when i set the text.

```
double myValue = 25000;
myInput.setText(String.valueOf(myValue).replace(".0", ""));
```