# Is it possible to restrict a EditTextPreference to numbers?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I have an `EditTextPreference` in the settings of my app for which I only want to accept positive decimal numbers:

```
<EditTextPreference
    android:key="annual_vacation_setting"
    android:title="@string/enter_annual_vacation"
    android:defaultValue="@string/default_annual_vacation"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true" />
```

Unfortunately, the `inputType` attribute doesn't seem to have any effect. The user can input arbitrary strings.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46495367/12478830

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**

You need to set `inputType` to its `EditText` after `onBinding`:

```
editTextPrefView.setOnBindEditTextListener { editText ->
    editText.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER
}
```

**Solution 2**

Use this [FIX library](https://github.com/takisoft/preferencex-android#hijacked-edittextpreference). It will let you directly set
`android:inputType=numberDecimal` to `EditTextPreference` in **XML**