# Checking if user entered nothing or string instead of Integer

Tags: android

How would I go about validating a user entered an Integer and not Nothing. The user must enter something into the editText and it must a be an integer. How do I go about validating it.

I have this:

```
int age = Integer.parseInt(editAge.getText().toString());

if(editAge.getText().toString().equals("")){
      Toast messsage please try again
}else they are good to go
```

I do not know how to test if the edit text is blank or a string is entered

Comment: In addition to the answer given, you can also limit text entered to just numbers, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200689/android-limiting-edittext-to-numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Integer.parseInt() to convert the entered string into an integer. If it succeeds then it is an integer. If it doesn't, it is not an integer.

```
String text = editAge.getText().toString();
try {
   int num = Integer.parseInt(text);
   Log.d("",num+" is a number");
   // Good to go.
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
   // Toast message. Please try again.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of validating, you can use input type like below. With this, user can enter number only

```html
<EditText
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:inputType="numberDecimal"
   android:numeric="integer"/>
```